# Which sorting method is best to sort 1 million integers of size 0 to 2^40 so that I get the smallest tilde time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose you need to sort 10 million integers, each in the range 0 to 2^40. How would you do it? Which method, among the ones we have seen, gives the smallest tilde time complexity.

Examples of possible methods: Key index counting, LDS, MSD, 3 way radix quicksort, suffix quicksort...

Comment: radix sort base 2^10 would take 1 read pass to create counts / indexes, then  4 radix sort passes.

Comment: What do you mean by "among the ones we have seen"? Who is "we"? Stack Overflow members? Your class?